# TS2322: Type 'D[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Here's the code:

```js
export interface CreateFilterOptionsConfig < T > {
  stringify ? : (option: T) => string;
}

interface AutoCompleteFieldProps < D extends object > {
  options: Array < D > ;
  labelKey: keyof D;
}

const AutoCompleteField = < D extends object > ({
  options,
  labelKey,
}: AutoCompleteFieldProps < D > ) => {
  const filter = createFilterOptions < D > ({
    stringify: (option) => option[labelKey]
  });

  return <div > < /div>
}
```

Needless to say, it's trimmed for brevity. The idea is that if I provided an object like the following to `AutoCompleteField`:

```
{ id: 0, myLabel: "some label" }
```

...and the value `myLabel`, the `filter` function would return the string "some label". This allows me to provide arbitrary types as long as I provide the key field from which the display string should be returned.

Yet I get the following error:

```
TS2322: Type '(option: D) => D[keyof D]' is not assignable to type '(option: D) => string'.
Type 'D[keyof D]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'D[string] | D[number] | D[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
Type 'D[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that neither your object `D` only has strings nor the `labelKey` is restricted to keys containing a string.

If you want to restrict `D` to strings only, you should indicate `<D extends {[key: string]: string}>`.

If you want to restrict `labelKey`, it is a little bit more complex:

```js
type StringPropertyNames<T> = {
  [K in keyof T]: T[K] extends string ? K : never;
}[keyof T];

interface AutoCompleteFieldProps < D extends object > {
  options: Array < D > ;
  labelKey: StringPropertyNames<D>;
}
```

The `StringPropertyNames` type takes only the keys of `T` where the values are string.

Comment: I want to restrict `labelKey` to keys with values of `string` only, yes. Thank you very much, I will try this.

Comment: Actually this is simply giving a longer error: TS2322: Type '(option: D) => D[StringPropertyNames<D>]' is not assignable to type '(option: D) => string'.   Type 'D[StringPropertyNames<D>]' is not assignable to type 'string'.     Type 'D[D[keyof D] extends string ? keyof D : never]' is not assignable to type 'string'.       Type 'D[keyof D]' is not assignable to type 'string'.         Type 'D[string] | D[number] | D[symbol]' is not assignable to type 'string'.           Type 'D[string]' is not assignable to type 'string'.

Comment: This will actually prevent you from using a key which does not match a string in your option object, but Typescript does not manage to guess that the result will then be a string. I think you will need to add a type assertion like `option[labelKey] as string`.